# How to call a function in.js

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Please be nice as I am still learning code in JavaScript.

I am working on a FireFox Add-on and would like to know how I could call a function from an external .js file.

I have a main.js file with the following code:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
//var notification = require("notification-box");
//var notification = require("notification-box").NotificationBox({
//'value': 'important-message',
//'label': 'Secure Connection Established',
//'priority': 'WARNING_HIGH',
//'image': self.data.url("secure.png"),

//});

pageMod.PageMod({   
  include: "https://*", 
var notification = require("notification-box").NotificationBox({
  'value': 'important-message',
  'label': 'Secure Connection Established',
  'priority': 'WARNING_HIGH',
  'image': self.data.url("secure.png"),

});
```

The NotificationBox function calls another external file called notification-box.js which its purpose is to show a notification bar at the top of the page.

The purpose of the above code is to show a notification if the the user visits a HTTPS page.

When I run the above code I get the error "missing : after property list"

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Comment: This is now resolved. Instead of calling an external function, I've changed the code to call an external .js file as to which I could then run that intending function with conditions attached.

Answer (score 1):

You cant stick a var in the middle of an object:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://*",
    notification: require("notification-box").NotificationBox({
        'value': 'important-message',
        'label': 'Secure Connection Established',
        'priority': 'WARNING_HIGH',
        'image': self.data.url("secure.png"),
    }),
    'some_other_key': 'some other value'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked by showing the actual notification, but not on a secure page. This maybe a separate issue I need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

```
'image': self.data.url("secure.png"),
```

Remove `,` and it should be fine

Comment: In firefox its ok to leave that last comma